# How to update node value in a linkedlist using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linked-list, find

I'd like to update a node value in a linked list using linq. Traversing the list, finding the right node and updating the value works, but I think a linq method could be cleaner.

This is my attempt which gives a compile error `cannot convert lambda expression to type <Main.Globals.Node> because it is not a delegate type`:

```
// get IV value where Node BookID=4
var val = Globals.BookLL.Where(B => B.BookID == 4).Select(B => B.IV).Single();

// can update first node using this method
Globals.BookLL.First.Value.IV = 999;

// can upddate IV by traversing list
LinkedListNode<Globals.Node> Current = Globals.BookLL.First;
while (Current != null)
            {
                if(Current.Value.BookID==4)
                {
                    Current.Value.IV = 444;
                }
                Current = Current.Next;
            }

   // how can you update IV using linq?
   Globals.BookLL.Find(B => B.BookID == 4).Value.IV = 999;        // cannot convert lambda expression to type <Main.Globals.Node> because it is not a delegate type
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If it is a Linq method, ou should invoke `First`: `Globals.BookLL.First()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Globals.BookLL.Single(b => b.BookId == 4).IV = 44;
```

You can use `single` if BookIds are unique.

Comment: Can I use the same method for a nested linked list? I get an error with this:  ``var K = Globals.BookLL.Single(B => B.BookID == 4);  var G=K.GreeksLL.Single(G => G.BookOrComp == "Book" && G.GreekType == "Delta");   a local or parameter name G cannot be declared in this scope...``

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
Globals.BookLL val = Globals.BookLL.Single(B => B.BookID == 4);
```

to determine the item, you can use `Find()`

```
Globals.BookLL.Find(val).Value.IV = 999;
```

to change it's value

Comment: I get a compile error on the first ``BookLL  - the type or namespace could not be found...``

Comment: @Zeus replaced `BookLL` with `Globals.BookLL`

Answer (score 0):

```
Globals.BookLL.Find(B => B.BookID == 4)
```

This returns an `IEnumerable<Globals.Node>`, you should use LINQ's `First()`:

```
Globals.BookLL.First(B => B.BookID == 4).Value.IV = 999;
```

Comment: `First()` returns a `BookLL` which has not a `Value` property

Comment: Thanks but I think fubo is right. I get a compile error on ``IV`` saying that ``double does not contain a definition for IV and no extension method IV accepting ....``